# Regularizing the intercept

Tags: regularization

I am reading *The Elements of Statistical Learning* and regarding regularized logistic regression it says:

> "As with the lasso, we typically do not penalize the intercept term"

and I am wondering in which situations you would penalize the intercept?

Looking at regularization in general, couldn't one think of scenarios where penalizing the intercept would lead to a better EPE (expected prediction error)? Although we increase the bias wouldn't we in some scenarios still reduce the EPE?

**EDIT**
It might be that we cant reduce the EPE while penalizing the intercept. But are there scenarios where the following statement isnt correct: "The model will get a lower Expected Prediction Error if we do not penalize the intercept"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there exist scenarios where it makes sense to penalize the intercept, if that aligns with domain knowledge.

However in real world, more often we do not just *penalize* the magnitude of intercept, but *enforce* it to be zero. This happens in cases where we expect the output to be 0 if all inputs are 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer